# Adding badge icon to iOS 10 on Xcode 8.3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, icons, badge

Here is my AppDelegate (made from a developer in Xcode 8.3, iOS10), it is working perfectly to send notifications, but I would like to add a badge to my iPhone dashboard.

I tried to add `application.applicationBadgeNumber = XX` but the XX never updates, it stays on XX no matter if there are 5 new notifications or none (which should delete the badge at this point).

How can I make badge icon flows correctly to show if there is a new notification or not in the app?

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import IQKeyboardManagerSwift
import UserNotifications

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
 let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {


        // Override point for customization after application launch.

   //     UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.black
       UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor(red:0.00, green:0.81, blue:1.00, alpha:1.0)
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor(red:0.00, green:0.81, blue:1.00, alpha:1.0)]//[NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.white]



        /*

        let navBackgroundImage:UIImage! = UIImage(named: "background.png")
        UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(navBackgroundImage, for: .default)

        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.black
*/

        UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor(red:0.00, green:0.81, blue:1.00, alpha:1.0)

        UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red:0.98, green:0.98, blue:0.98, alpha:1.0)

        FIRApp.configure()
        IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = true


        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(self.tokenRefreshNotification),
                                               name: .firInstanceIDTokenRefresh,
                                               object: nil)






        let storyboard = self.grabStoryboard()
        // display storyboard
        self.window!.rootViewController! = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()!
        self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return true
    }

    func grabStoryboard() -> UIStoryboard {
        // determine screen size
        let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height

        print ("screen : \(screenHeight)")
        var storyboard: UIStoryboard?
        switch screenHeight {
        // iPhone 4s
        case 480:
            print("ici iphone4")
            storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "iphone4", bundle: nil)
        // iPhone 5s
        default:
            // it's an iPad
            print("ici default")
            storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        }

        return storyboard!
    }



    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
        FIRMessaging.messaging().disconnect()
        print("Disconnected from FCM.")
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
        connectToFcm()


    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {

        // FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: .un)

        // FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: .unknown)


        let chars = (deviceToken as NSData).bytes.bindMemory(to: CChar.self, capacity: deviceToken.count)
        var token = ""

        for i in 0..<deviceToken.count {
            token += String(format: "%02.2hhx", arguments: [chars[i]])
        }

        FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.unknown)

        print("Device Token = ", token)


    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("Did Fail to Register for Remote Notifications")
        print("\(error), \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }



    func tokenRefreshNotification(_ notification: Notification) {


        if let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() {
            //      constantsApp.user.deviceToken = refreshedToken
            print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")
        }
        // Connect to FCM since connection may have failed when attempted before having a token.
        connectToFcm()
    }



    func connectToFcm() {
        FIRMessaging.messaging().connect { (error) in
            if (error != nil) {
                print("Unable to connect with FCM. \(error ?? "" as! Error)")
            } else {
                print("Connected to FCM.")
            }
        }
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }

    // [START receive_message]
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification
        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)
    }



    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification
        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
        // Print message ID.
        // Print full message.

        print(userInfo)

        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }
    // [END receive_message]
  }




@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
        // Print message ID.
        print("Message ID: \(userInfo["gcm.message_id"]!)")

        // Print full message.
        print("%@", userInfo)
    }

    @available(iOS 10, *)
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        print("Userinfo \(response.notification.request.content.userInfo)")
        //    print("Userinfo \(response.notification.request.content.userInfo)")
    }
}

extension AppDelegate : FIRMessagingDelegate {
    // Receive data message on iOS 10 devices.
    func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(_ remoteMessage: FIRMessagingRemoteMessage) {
        print("%@", remoteMessage.appData)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For iOS 10:**

You need to implement UserNotifications into your AppDelegate.

```
import UserNotifications

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { (granted, error) in
        if error != nil {
            //
        }
    }
    return true

}
```

Then you can do:

```
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.badge = 10 // your badge count
```

**For older iOS:**

```
let badgeCount: Int = 123
let application = UIApplication.sharedApplication()

if #available(iOS 7.0, *) {
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = badgeCount
}

if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Badge], categories: nil))
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = badgeCount
}

if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Badge], categories: nil))
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = badgeCount
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer but I am very new to swift, so can you please tell exactly where to place your answer inside MY file above?

Comment: like i said in my answer: the first in the AppDelegate.swift. The second wherever you want.

Comment: UNUserNotificationCenter.curren... right before your return in your applicationdidfinishloa..

Comment: WONDERFUL i will try now

Comment: here is the code on my file like you told me, but it is not working unfortunately...

Comment: let storyboard = self.grabStoryboard()
        // display storyboard
        self.window!.rootViewController! = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()!
        self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
            
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { (granted, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    //
                }
            }
            let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
            content.badge = 10 // your badge count
            
        return true
    }

Comment: ?? you should do it in the {} after the error check or somewhere later and not in the same function. And why do you post your code without any comment?

Comment: I am sorry, like i said... i am new to swift and i don't really understand what you are trying to say, for you it must be so obvious but for me you are speaking chinese. For example: when you say that i should do it in the {} after the error check i don't even understand what you are talking about! I should do what? And what should i comment? I already said commented that it Was not working... so i am not sure what you are talking about :-)

Comment: Maybe i could pay you and you fix 1-2 things on my ios app? Because i am not good enough to understand what you are telling me...

Comment: That's not how this site works. I`m happy if you just accept the answer: Put it in the  if error != nil {
            HERE
        } brakets for example. But normally you would change the badge somewhere entirely else in your application. If you really want to pay me or someone else for work on your problems just massage them/me via email outside of Stackoverflow.